# Different execution policies at runtime

Tags: c++, parallel-processing

In C++17, a number of functions in the `algorithm` header now can take an execution policy. I can for example define and call a function like this:

```
template <class ExecutionPolicy>
void f1(const std::vector<std::string>& vec, const std::string& elem, ExecutionPolicy&& policy) {
    const auto it = std::find(
        std::forward<ExecutionPolicy>(policy),
        vec.cbegin(), vec.cend(), elem
    );
}

std::vector<std::string> vec;
f1(vec, "test", std::execution::seq);
```

However I haven't found a good way to use different policies at runtime. For example when I want to use a different policy depending on some input file.

I toyed around with variants, but in the end the problem was always the different types of `std::execution::seq`, `std::execution::par` and `std::execution::par_unseq`.

A working but cumbersome solution would look like this:

```
void f2(const std::vector<std::string>& vec, const std::string& elem, const int policy) {
    const auto it = [&]() {
        if (policy == 0) {
            return std::find(
                std::execution::seq,
                vec.cbegin(), vec.cend(), elem
            );
        }
        else if (policy == 1) {
            return std::find(
                std::execution::par,
                vec.cbegin(), vec.cend(), elem
            );
        }
        else{
            return std::find(
                std::execution::par_unseq,
                vec.cbegin(), vec.cend(), elem
            );
        }
    };
}

f2(vec, "test", 0);
```

Is there any more elegant solution I'm overlooking?

edit: maybe I should be more precise. Let's say the goal is to save the policy in a variable that can have either of the three policies. That variable should be a parameter to the function.

Comment: This depends entirely on where the choice comes from. Without constraining that `policy` variable to being an `int`, for example, you can just literally pass an `ExecutionPolicy` into `f2`. But presumably you have some constraint, and we don't know what that is.

Comment: But the thing is, that the three policies do not have a common base class as far as I understood things. That's precisely what makes this so tricky

Comment: Oh, right. Well, meh. The best solution still depends on where that "choice" will come from. You might be able to use like a constexpr vector or something to map integers to types. Though that still doesn't completely help you. Not sure; good luck!

Answer (score 11, accepted):

The standard approach here is to separate the *selection* of a type from the *use* of the type: the latter takes the form of a function template instantiated several times by the former non-template function (or function template with fewer template parameters).

To avoid duplicating the normal parameters between these two layers, use a generic lambda as the template.  To avoid duplicating the selection logic, make a function template that calls whatever lambda with the appropriate policy:

```
enum Policy {seq,par,par_unseq};

template<class F>
auto maybe_parallel(F f,Policy p) {
  switch(p) {
  case seq: return f(std::execution::seq);
  case par: return f(std::execution::par);
  default: return f(std::execution::par_unseq);
  }
}

auto f2(const std::vector<std::string>& vec,
        const std::string& elem,Policy p) {
  return maybe_parallel
    ([&](auto &pol) {return std::find(pol,vec.begin(),vec.end(),elem);},p);
}
```

Comment: Hey wow that seems clever. I'm gonna try it later. Thanks a lot!

Answer (score 1):

An alternative approach is to use `std::variant` and `std::visit` for this purpose.

```
using parallel_policy = std::variant
                        <
                         std::execution::sequenced_policy,
                         std::execution::parallel_policy,
                         std::execution::parallel_unsequenced_policy,
                         std::execution::unsequenced_policy
                        >;

void f2(const std::vector<std::string>& vec,
        const std::string&              elem,
        const parallel_policy           policy
       )
{
    std::visit
    (
        [&](auto policy_real)
        {
            f1(vec, elem, policy_real);
        },
        policy
    );
}
```