# C++ template usage based on selecting type dynamically

Tags: c++, templates

I'm trying to find an efficient way to invoke a specific C++ template type based dynamic value of a variable. Currently I'm not clear on how to approach this, except by using large and ugly if/else selector for a large set of permutations as in the example below. As you can see this is not pretty.

Instead I'd like to invoke suitable template dynamically without huge if/else selector...

Any advise from the C++ template masters out there would be much appreciated.

```
// crude generic data converter template invoked based on dynamic in/out buffer type
template <class dstType, class srcType>
void ConvertCopy(unsigned char* dst, const unsigned char* src, int size)
{
    // requires same in/out buffer same dimensions
    if (typeid(srcType) != typeid(dstType)) 
    {
        dstType* c_dst = (dstType*)dst;
        srcType* c_src = (srcType*)src;
        for(int i=0;i<size;i++)
            c_dst[i] = (dstType)c_src[i];
    }
    else
        memcpy(dst, src, size * sizeof(srcType)); // Plain copy
}

void test()
{
    const int buffersize = 100;

    int inbuffer[buffersize];
    double outbuffer[buffersize];
    unsigned char* anyIn = (unsigned char*)inbuffer;
    unsigned char* anyOut = (unsigned char*)outbuffer;

    int my_in_type = 1;
    int my_out_type = 3;

    if(my_in_type == 1) { // int
        if(my_out_type == 1) ConvertCopy<int, int>(anyOut, anyIn, buffersize); // int -> int
        if(my_out_type == 2) ConvertCopy<float, int>(anyOut, anyIn, buffersize); // int -> float
        if(my_out_type == 3) ConvertCopy<double, int>(anyOut, anyIn, buffersize); // int -> double
        // ...
    }
    else if(my_in_type == 2) { // unsigned int
        if(my_out_type == 1) ConvertCopy<int, unsigned int>(anyOut, anyIn, buffersize); // unsigned int -> int
        if(my_out_type == 2) ConvertCopy<float, unsigned int>(anyOut, anyIn, buffersize); // unsignedint -> float
        if(my_out_type == 3) ConvertCopy<double, unsigned int>(anyOut, anyIn, buffersize); // unsigned int -> double
        // ...
    }
    else {}
    // ...
}
```

Comment: So you just need one `if`/`else` branch based on whether the types are the same or not?

Comment: If C++17 is available to you, you might like [`std::any`](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/utility/any)

Comment: Off-topic: `int size`? How meaningful are sizes like -1, -7, -10, -12, ...???

Comment: `memcpy` can fail badly if applied on complex types like `std::string`. Better use `std::copy` instead, if templates are involved.

Comment: Templates and dynamic types are contradictory concepts. *If* you can, let template parameters get deduced: `convertCopy(DstType* dst, SrcType const* src)`. If you cannot, a lookup table might be an option: `void (*pointers[])(unsigned char*, unsigned char const*, size_t) = { convertCopy<int, int>, convertCopy<int, double>, ... };`. Then you could calculate the appropriate index with `outType * NumberOfTypes + inType`.

Comment: thanks for the helpful feedback. lookup table is interesting approach.

Answer (score 3):

There’s no way (short of the very young [JIT proposals](http://open-std.org/JTC1/SC22/WG21/docs/papers/2019/p1609r2.html)) to avoid a branch or lookup table: it is a feature that different specializations of a function template can have **unrelated** types (with some restrictions on the parameter types, especially when supporting deduction), making it implausible to support a call with a dynamic template argument in the type system even if it were known to be drawn from a small set.  (Yours all happen to be `void(unsigned char*,const unsigned char*,int)`, but for consistency the rules do not consider that.)

That said, the boilerplate can be expressed **efficiently** in [cases like this](https://stackoverflow.com/a/53001490/8586227) where the type doesn’t vary:

```
template<class D>
auto copier(int s) {
  switch(s) {
  case 1: return ConvertCopy<D,int>;
  case 2: return ConvertCopy<D,unsigned>;
  // …
  }
}
void test() {
  // …
  [](int d) {
    switch(d) {
    case 1: return copier<int>;
    case 2: return copier<float>;
    case 3: return copier<double>;
    // …
    }
  }(my_out_type)(my_in_type)(anyOut,anyIn,buffersize);
}
```

This approach reduces the verbosity to *O*(*m*+*n*) from *O*(*mn*).  It may help if you think of the extra sets of parentheses as being separate because they *are* like “runtime template argument lists”.

It would of course be possible to generalize this to produce a value of any consistent type from a metafunction with (for practicality) a known range of interesting inputs.

Comment: thanks for clarifying the subject with limitations and available options.

Answer (score 0):

MSVC compiles down to it's `.NET` code (oversimplification), which allows you to use elements from other Microsoft languages. In Visual C++, there is a keyword known as 'generic` and it works like a template but may allow for what you're wanting.

Microsoft has a few pages of documentation on this, but here is the link to the [overview page](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/cpp/extensions/overview-of-generics-in-visual-cpp?view=vs-2019).