# Generic way to use fs::recursive_directory_iterator() and fs::directory_iterator()

Tags: c++, c++17

I need to iterate over folder either recursively or not (given the boolean parameter). I have discovered there is `fs::recursive_directory_iterator()` and also `fs::directory_iterator()`. In Java, I would expect them to implement the same interface or share the common ancestor so that I could substitute the needed one. But for some reason the two iterators do not share the common ancestor, forcing the to write the code like:

```
  if (recursive_) {
    path = recursive_iterator_->path();
    recursive_iterator_++;
  } else {
    path = plain_iterator_->path();
    plain_iterator_++;
  }
```

I cannot believe this is how it is supposed to work. I also initially assumed there are some options to turn off recursion for recursive_directory_iterator but seems no any between std::filesystem::directory_options.

The value is not known at the compile time. I think it should be possible to use something like a closure or even subclass with virtual method but looks a bit like overkill.

Should I simply use conditionals switching between the two iterators as needed, or there are better approaches?

Comment: The magic word is "template".

Comment: No, the value is not known at the compile time. It is an object property that has a setter, setRecursive(bool).

Comment: Interesting question! Both of them do seem to return an object of same type: `directory_entry`. Would that help in your implementation?

Comment: *Should I simply use conditionals switching between the two iterators as needed, or there are better approaches?* If you already have the conditional code working, I'd just keep it.  Since `recursive_` wont change while iterating the branch predictor should get it right every time (possibly after one or two misses).

Comment: *In Java, I would expect them to implement the same interface or share the common ancestor so that I could substitute the needed one.* -- C++ standard classes tend to stay away from having to force virtual functions and polymorphism into the code base.  For Java, you just take it for granted that everything is virtual.  C++ cannot afford that expense.

Comment: @PaulMcKenzie `std::` has loads of polymorphism. It's mostly *static* polymorphism.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> implement the same interface

They do. They are both [*InputIterator*s](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/named_req/InputIterator), that dereference to `const std::filesystem::directory_entry&`.

C++ avoids `virtual` by default.

You can use [`boost::any_range`](https://www.boost.org/doc/libs/1_72_0/libs/range/doc/html/range/reference/ranges/any_range.html) to type erase the recursiveness.

```
template <typename... Args>
auto make_directory_range(bool recursive, Args... args) {
    return recursive
        ? boost::make_iterator_range(fs::recursive_directory_iterator(args...), fs::recursive_directory_iterator()) | boost::adaptors::type_erased()
        : boost::make_iterator_range(fs::directory_iterator(args...), fs::directory_iterator());
}

using iterator_t = decltype(make_directory_range(true).begin());

auto range = make_directory_range(recursive_, args...);
iterator_t iterator = range.begin();
iterator_t end = range.end();
```

Comment: Boost solution looks really nice, just the type of iterator_ is now extremely long and verbose.

Comment: @h22 that's what `decltype` is for

Comment: I prefer Audrius Meškauskas original version. Everything else makes something simple hard to read for no reason.

Answer (score 0):

The [usual](https://stackoverflow.com/a/59170187/8586227) [way](https://stackoverflow.com/a/53001490/8586227) of dealing with a static polymorphism situation like this is to use a helper template:

```
template<class F,class ...AA>
void for_each_file(F f,bool rec,AA &&...aa) {
  const auto g=[&](auto end) {
    std::for_each(decltype(end)(std::forward<AA>(aa)...),
                  end,std::move(f));
  };
  if(rec) g(fs::recursive_directory_iterator());
  else g(fs::directory_iterator());
}
std::size_t count(const fs::path &d,bool rec) {
  std::size_t n=0;
  for_each_file([&](fs::directory_entry) {++n;},rec,d);
  return n;
}
```

This approach does have limitations: it makes it harder to `break` out of the “loop”, for example.

Answer (score 0):

Instead of using `boost::adaptors::type_erased` explicitly, you can also use `boost::any_range` with implicit type conversion. This may help with the readability of your code.

> Please note that it is frequently unnecessary to use the type_erased adaptor. It is often better to use the implicit conversion to any_range. [(1)](https://valelab4.ucsf.edu/svn/3rdpartypublic/boost/libs/range/doc/html/range/reference/adaptors/reference/type_erased.html)

```cpp
boost::any_range<fs::directory_entry, boost::single_pass_traversal_tag> iterator;

if (recursive) {
    iterator = boost::make_iterator_range(fs::recursive_directory_iterator(...), fs::recursive_directory_iterator());
}
else {
    iterator = boost::make_iterator_range(fs::directory_iterator(...), fs::directory_iterator());
}

auto begin = iterator.begin();
auto end = iterator.end();

// do whatever you want
```

If your `fs` namespace is `boost::filesystem` instead of `std::filesystem`. You can also omit the `boost::make_iterator_range`:

```cpp
//...

if (recursive) {
    iterator = fs::recursive_directory_iterator(...);
}
else {
    iterator = fs::directory_iterator(...);
}

//...
```