# How to do polymorphism with template?

Tags: c++

I have created a Linked List class with a template to hold any kind of data type.

I want to do a `switch` where I ask the user what type he will use (`int`, `char`, `string`, etc). I know that I can do this with polymorphism, but I must create a class for every type. Using a template, the compiler obligates me to initialize my class to one type, so I must initialize every type before.

So, my question is, can I create only one object of `List` that will choose the element type at runtime, without having to create a class for every type?

For example:

```
List<> list;
list = new List<int>
```

Comment: [`std::any`](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/utility/any) is probably the most direct way to do this, but note that cases where a container of anything is actually useful are extremely rare.

Comment: While editing, I realized you don't want a container of anything, you want a container of one thing, but that one thing isn't known until runtime. Ignore my rantings. `std::any` might still be the easiest way to do this, though.

Comment: If the element types to choose from are limited, you can use `std::variant` instead. Then you would have a single type `List<variant>` to instantiate, in which you can then push the user's values.

Comment: Side note: Your English is fine. I have more trouble with the native English who think the whole world is a mobile phone text conversation.

Comment: Figure out what you want the binary representation to be.  All the types you can use have some byte size (their sizeof).  Some require destructors to be called.  Where will the bytes reside and how will you know to destruct properly?

Comment: If you don’t need to change from one type to another during the lifetime of `list`, you can apply the [function template trick](https://stackoverflow.com/a/53001490/8586227).