# How to write a macro that can dispatch template functions with template parameter

Tags: c++

I have a template class `Cache`, it has methods like `Get`, `Put`, `Evict` and a CacheEvictStrategy (FIFO, LRU, LFU).

```cpp
template<typename KeyType, typename ElemType>
class Cache

template<typename KeyType, typename ElemType>
void Cache::Get(uint32_t num_query, KeyType* queries, ElemType* result, bool* find_mask){
}
```

Since the three types of CacheEvictStrategy share a lot of codes, I write most common code in Cache::Get, it will call another template function `GetInternal`, which will act differently according to different CacheEvictStrategy.

```cpp
template<typename KeyType, typename ElemType, CacheEvictStrategy Strategy>
__global__ void GetInternal(uint32_t num_query, KeyType* queries, ElemType* result, bool* find_mask)


template<typename KeyType, typename ElemType>
void Cache::Get(uint32_t num_query, KeyType* queries, ElemType* result, bool* find_mask){
    // common logic
    GetInternal<KeyType, ElemType, Strategy><<<grid,block>>>(num_query,queries,result,find_mask);
}
```

Since Strategy is decided in runtime. I want to write a macro to dispatch it.But I also have `Put`, `Evict` functions, I want to write a marco that takes a function and CacheEvictStrategy.But only i know the CacheEvictStrategy can I get the template function since CacheEvictStrategy is a template parameter. I don't want to write a macro for each function like below:

```cpp
#define DISPATCH_GET(strategy,grid,block,...){ \
     switch(strategy){
     case LRU:
     GetInternal<KeyType,ElemType,LRU><<<grid, block>>>(__VA__ARGS__) \
     ....                       \
     }                          \

#define DISPATCH_PUT
#define DISPATCH_EVICT
```

Is there some ways to solve my problem? I would appreciate it if someone could give me some advice :)

Comment: *"Since Strategy is decided in runtime..."* Then how come you're passing it as a template argument which are compile time? Like in `GetInternal<KeyType, ElemType, Strategy>`

Comment: Why use a macro when a [template will do](https://stackoverflow.com/a/53001490/8586227)?

Comment: @user12002570 actually that is my problem. I can't write code like `GetInternal<KeyType, ElemType, Strategy>` since Strategy is decided in runtime. So I want to write a macro to dispatch different CacheEvictStrategy.

Comment: @DavisHerring thanks for your advice. But how can I pass in different function using template? Since I also have `Put`, `Evict` function besides `Get`. How can I use a template for all this functions?

Comment: You use a suitable runtime dispatch mechanism, such as virtual functions in an inheritance based hierarchy.

Comment: @n.m.couldbeanAI Since GetInternal function is a kernel function, I have tried to do runtime dispatch using polymorphism, but finally I gave up. I think using dynamic dispatch may not be a good choice in gpu.

Comment: It might a XY problem. Seems like you want a factor pattern instead.

Comment: @shadow: You pass a simple generic lambda to a common dispatcher in each of those cases, as I illustrated.  Each such lambda can then supply the correct template argument to the actual implementation function.  (Sometimes you have to wrap a value like `LRU` as a type, as with `std::integral_constant`, for this trick to work.)